# Percentage for each row - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Searches table for pets. I want to see the percentage of search per Animal-name.

My query is:

```
Select AVG(a.search_count) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT
ROW)*100 AS Precentage
from (select [Animal-Name], count (*) as search_count
      from dbo.Searches
      group by [Animal-Name]
     ) as a
```

What I get from the second select (inside the from):

[image]

so what I need now is the percentage of search_count result for each animal-name.
any idea what is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a simple ratio:

```
select [Animal-Name], count(*) as search_count,
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from dbo.Searches
group by [Animal-Name];
```

The `* 1.0` is because the code looks like SQL Server and SQL Server does integer arithmetic -- so `1 / 2` is `0` rather than `0.5`.